# How can I change the drop down arrow's color of this MultiSelectFormField widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to change the color of the drop down arrow from black to grey of this MultiSelectFormField widget. There is no property to change it on the documentation. Is there a way
to change it? I tried using ThemeData and use indicatorColor but that does not change anything.

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border(
      bottom: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.white)
    )
  ),
  child: Theme(
    data: ThemeData(
      indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
    child: MultiSelectFormField(
        autovalidate: false,
        title: Row(
          children: [
            Icon(
              Icons.check_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(width: width*.02,),
            Text(
              "Goals",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: height * .025),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        hintWidget: Text(
          "",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 0),
        ),
        fillColor: Colors.transparent,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        dataSource: [
          {
            "display": "Goal 1",
            "value": 1,
          },
          {
            "display": "Goal 2",
            "value": 2,
          },
          {
            "display": "Goal 3",
            "value": 3,
          },
          {
            "display": " Goal 4",
            "value": 4,
          }
        ],
        textField: 'display',
        valueField: 'value',
        required: false,
        onSaved: (value) {
          print('The value is $value');
        }),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is possible to change the color of the drop-down arrow in MultiSelectFormField.
In this package, the color of the drop-down arrow seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

might want to try to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown) instead.
It has multi-select and search as well and fully customizable.

example for multi-select:

```
List<String> items = ["select 1", "select 2", "select 3"];
...
Container(
   decoration: BoxDecoration(
     border: Border(
     bottom: BorderSide(width: 1,color: Colors.white)
     )
   ),
   child: Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
        indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        child: SearchableDropdown.multiple(
           label: "Multi-select"
           hint: "Select an item",
           items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                   value: item,
                   child: Text(item),
               );
               }).toList(),
           onSaved: (value) {
             print('The value is $value');
           }),
           //set icon here
           clearIcon: Icon(Icons.clear_all),
           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle),
           //set icon color here
           iconDisabledColor: Colors.brown,
           iconEnabledColor: Colors.indigo,
           isExpanded: true,
   ),
  ),
```